# Is there an explanation to why Superman is helping USA government?

Tags: dc, superman, character-motivation

Superman is presented as a global superhero compared to people like Oliver who rarely take their offense out of their zones. But when the truth is so, why does Superman fight a country to protect USA? Is it because he is also used for ulterior motives like Captain america or is it his own patriotic feelings?

Comment: I would assume you're only referring to the media in which he does this. In some stories, such as the Injustice storyline, he completely ignores, opposes, and oppresses the US government.

Comment: Superman stands for Truth, Justice and (depending on the continuity) the American Way. Obviously it's now more PC to have him [renounce his US citizenship](http://comicsalliance.com/superman-renounces-us-citizenship/) and claim to be a global citizen but in prior years, he was still a loyal American,

Comment: Frankly, it's sensible. Nations disavow knowledge of assassins in order to maintain diplomatic relations. Superman's actions are frequently far further-reaching and more controversial, so for the purposes of verisimilitude, he needs autonomy. He still believes in the American Way; it simply is not "*enough* anymore." Now, if Captain America became Captain U.N., I might believe that they were being PC....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Siegel and Shuster who created Superman were both first generation Jewish immigrants, and Superman as a character is seen as being the ultimate immigrant - to Earth, fleeing a troubled (and exploded) homeland. He is a Superman, but not the Aryan blond ideal of racial purity. He protects the weak, stands for truth and freedom and fairly early in his publication history goes off to fight Nazis.

To sell to an American audience, the authors needed to ensure that Superman was on their side and represented their feelings and ideals - the same ideals which perhaps attracted their immigrant families to the USA. Hence the principles of Truth, Justice and the American way.

Because he is a hero, by definition Superman will fight bad people - to the audience, these bad people were those who opposed America - spies, Nazis, saboteurs or those who opposed its values - criminals, cowards, racists etc. The radio show famously combatted the real KKK by leaking its codewords, secret rituals etc and showing them as villains.

The core values of Superman are more important than national laws - like Captain America, he can be seen to be on the side of the spirit of American not the letter of the law. Superman's belief in American equality trumps discriminatory laws - he's not Moore's Comedian (from Watchmen.)

As the comics got more complex and looked at more morally difficult areas than just fighting Nazis and muggers the decision was made for Superman to lend a helping hand rather than just to solve all problems with his power (Ian Gordon, The Moral World of Superman)

Different writers have taken the character in different directions - playing up his alien-ness, his power and his place as a 1940s hero in a global market of people and ideas.

In universe, Superman supports America because it's his adopted home, and reflects the values which the Kents raised him with. If the pod had landed in South Africa, China, Britain or whereever he likely would have been instilled with those values. Red Son tells an alternate history where Superman lands in the USSR and is raised with Soviet values and loyalty to the Motherland.

America's role as a superpower and it positioning as World Policeman, align it with Superman and Superman with it - at least in spirit. The problem occurs that global problems tend to have more complex causes and solutions than the original crimefighting comics can solve. Just hurling the dictator of North Korea into space won't solve the myriad of problems that the nation has, let alone the problems of the world.

Many modern comic books struggle with this problem - Watchmen most notably also The Authority, Ex Machina etc. You can't punch global inequality in the face.

However, for all its flaws America and the principles on which it was founded are ones Superman (an adopted American hero and American publication) can stand behind.

Comment: It's worth noting that the 'and the American way' bit wasn't added until the show was remade for radio.

Comment: I rather love how this was addressed in Superboy Prime by JMS; Supes finds himself at a tropical island under a dictator who manages to argue Supes out of saving the day.

Comment: How can superman help global inequality?

Comment: Like this? http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2305